# Angular2 *ngIf elegant way to change values

Tags: html, angular

I have a question. My html looks like this:

```html
<a
    href="/admin/companies"
    mat-button
    *ngIf="currentUserRole == 'Admin'"
  >
    <mat-icon
      matBadge="A"
      >business</mat-icon
    >
    Companies</a
  >
  <a 
     href="/companies" 
     mat-button 
     *ngIf="currentUserRole == 'Employer'">
    <mat-icon
      matBadge="E"
      >business</mat-icon
    >
    Companies</a
  >
```

Like you can see, i have the same button with diffrent `href` and `matBadge`. What displays depends on `cuurentUserRole`.

My question is, how from these two buttons make one with properly coded `*ngIf` condition to change what i want to? is it possible?

Comment: you can make a component with a single <a> element as its template, and pass in href and badge as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example

**In ts** 
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['button-overview-example.css'],
})
export class ButtonOverviewExample {
  currentUserRole : string = "Admin"
  roles = [{"url":"/admin/companies","id":"Admin","bid":"A","title":"Companies"},{"url":"/companies","id":"Employer","bid":"E","title":"Employee"}]
}
```

**In Html**

```
<div *ngFor="let role of roles">
<a 
    [href]="role.url"
    mat-button
    *ngIf="currentUserRole == role.id"
  >
    <mat-icon
      [matBadge]="role.bid"
      >business</mat-icon
    >
    {{role.title}}</a
  >
  </div>
```